# How we can post messages on Microsoft chat bot from an external source? Eg. External Rest API to MS chat bot

Tags: c#

How we can post messages on Microsoft chat bot from an external source? Eg. External Rest API to MS chat bot or console Application- MS chat bot, azure function- ms chat bot

Comment: Welcome to SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please add more to your question